# Cannot connect to postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I've written the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
            // attempt a connection
            // $conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgis user=postgres password=1234";
            // $dbh = pg_connect($conn_string);  

            $dbh = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=postgis user=postgres password=1234");

            if (!$dbh) {
                die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
            }

            // execute query
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM assets";
            $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);

            if (!$result) {
                die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
            }

            // iterate over result set
            // print each row
            while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo ": " . $row[0] . "<br />";
                echo ": " . $row[1] . "<p />";
            }

            // free memory
            pg_free_result($result);

            // close connection
            pg_close($dbh);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've saved this as `newphp.php` in `www` folder, and when I run this in my `localhost` (wamp server) the following error occurs

```
Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\wamp\www\newphp.php on line 18
```

Comment: Have you installed the libraries?

Comment: as Marco says, you're missing ps postgreql plug-in (library) for PHP, or you haven't enabled it in the PHP configuration

Comment: Remove the comment before the `extension=php_pgsql.dll` row in your php.ini, and restart your webserver

Answer (score 0):

WAMP does not have postgresql server or db in it.

DOWNLOAD local server having postgresql server WAPP
https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp

Comment: The questor seem to have manually added postresql to his wamp setup. I suspect answers that don't involve discarding what he has will be preferred.